# Minimap package line highlight always on

Tags: package, minimap

I've installed a `minimap` package and when I disable and save 'show minimap line highlight' it keeps showing the line highlight anyway:

[image]

Any obvious fixes, or is it just a bug in the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug -- the variable `minimap-highlight-line` is not anywhere within the workings of minimap -- i.e., it is only defined as a variable and mentioned in the comment (setting the variable will have the same effect as tying your shoe or drinking a cup of coffee).  See an open Github issue #5 regarding this bug:  https://github.com/dengste/minimap/issues/5 and related pull-request:  https://github.com/dengste/minimap/pull/7

Consider commenting out lines 519 to 523:  https://github.com/dengste/minimap/blob/master/minimap.el#L519  If the file is byte-compiled, then `M-x byte-compile-file` when you are done editing and saving your edits.

Alternatively, manually implement the same fix suggested in the above-mentioned pull-request.